# Make the fluent validator framework as loosely coupled

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, abstract, fluentvalidation

We've been using fluent validator framework across our asp.net project. As part of refactoring, we've decided to make fluent as loosely coupled validator and so we can replace it with any other tool easily anytime. And we thought of creating a wrapper around it, instead of using it directly and pollute all our validator classes with its namespace. But when I looked at the implementation, we are actually using an abstract class, not an interface.

```
using FluentValidation;
public class CreateRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateRequest> {}
```

How to wrap this abstract class into an interface, if possible? Or i use another wrapper class and duplicate all these method implementtaions as base references? how can i make my validator classes, not using fluent namespaces directly? any other best practices? thanks

Comment: I do not entirely understand your question, but you cannot make interface extending abstract class.

However, you can make generic abstract class like:
`public abstract class CreateRequestValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> {}`

Comment: I would like to add a wrapper around AbstractValidator (a fluentValidation abstract class) and use that instead of using fluent namesspace directly in the project, and so i have a loosely coupled 'validation' framework, which can be replaced with something else later.. I am thinking of writing a base class, which will have this 'Abstract' as a base class and will have all implementations.. I am inquiring is this fine and also would like to know of any best practices..